# HLSL Shader throws error when I try to use value

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

So I'm trying to learn myself some HLSL, but I am stumped. I'm writing a custom shader that has ambient lighting and a simple point-light color thing.

Here is the shader code:

```
`float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

// TODO: add effect parameters here.

float4 AmbientColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.5;

float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);

float3 LightPosition = float3(32, 32, 64);
float4 LightDiffuseColor = float4(0.3, 0.05, 0, 1); // intensity multiplier
float4 LightSpecularColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1); // intensity multiplier
float LightDistance = 50;

texture Texture;
sampler2D textureSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = (Texture);
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Pos: POSITION;
    float2 TexCoords : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 PosOut : POSITION;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD1;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Pos, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.PosOut= mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TexCoords;
    output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);

    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{ 
    float attenuation = saturate(1.0f - (length(input.PosOut - LightPosition) / LightDistance));

    float4 textureColor = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TextureCoordinate);
    textureColor.a = 1;

    float4 lightCol = 
    //LightDiffuseColor;
    mul(LightDiffuseColor, attenuation); 

    float4 ambient = (AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity);
    ambient.a = 1;

    return saturate(textureColor * ambient + lightCol);
}

technique Textured
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        // TODO: set renderstates here.

        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

`

The problem has been narrowed down to this section in the pixel shader:

```
float attenuation = saturate(1.0f - (length(input.PosOut - LightPosition) / LightDistance));    
...
float4 lightCol = 
//LightDiffuseColor;
mul(LightDiffuseColor, attenuation); 

return saturate(textureColor * ambient + lightCol);
```

It will work fine if i use just the LightDiffuseColor, but as soon as I try to multiply it, it throws this error:

```
GameContentShadersSimpleTexture.fx(35,21) error X4502 invalid ps_2_0 input semantic 'POSITION'
```

I'm using XNA for the engine. I'm kinda stumped here. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
    Doodles.

Edit:
Mkay, so I've narrowed it down to a pretty precise spot. It's when the length function is called for (input.PosOut - LightPosition)

Comment: I only see 3 numbers in initialization here: `float4 LightDiffuseColor = float4(0.3,0.05,0,1); // intensity multiplier`, could that be a problem? (i'm not familiar with hlsl)

Comment: yes, it's float4(0.3,0.05,0,1), looks a lot like float4(0.3,0.05,0.1) :P

Answer (score 0):

All right, so I have a solution for this. Instead of using per-pixel lighting for point lights, I should be using vertex lighting instead. The position semantic is not supported for pixel shader inputs, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#PS). But position still needs to be an ouput for the vertex shader, so it's included in the pixel shader input, but it cannot be used. My updated code is shown below:

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

// TODO: add effect parameters here.

float4 AmbientColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.5;

float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);

float3 LightPosition = float3(32, 32, 48);
float4 LightDiffuseColor = float4(0.3, 0.05, 0, 1);
float4 LightSpecularColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1); // intensity multiplier
float LightDistance = 100;

texture Texture;
sampler2D textureSampler = sampler_state {
    Texture = (Texture);
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR1;
    float3 Normal : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD1;
};

PixelShaderInput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    PixelShaderInput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position= mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    output.Color = mul(LightDiffuseColor,saturate(1.0f - (length(mul(input.Position, World) - LightPosition) / LightDistance)));
    output.TextureCoordinate = input.TextureCoordinate;
    output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);

    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(PixelShaderInput input) : COLOR0
{ 
    float4 textureColor = tex2D(textureSampler, input.TextureCoordinate);
    textureColor.a = 1;

    float4 ambient = (AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity);
    ambient.a = 1;

    return saturate(textureColor * ambient + input.Color);
}

technique Textured
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        // TODO: set renderstates here.

        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```